# Linking to all the developer iPad apps on the AppStore via URL

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

There is a way to link to all the developer's apps on the AppStore from any iOS app.

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/some-company-name/id1234567890
```

It will open the App Store app and show all the developer's apps for the iPhone and for the iPad and the page provides a couple of "View All" links for iPhone and iPad apps.

I wonder is there any way to link directly to the iPad-only apps page without visiting that intermediate screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not possible to "filter" the normal store links/developer links with the `&entity=iPadSofware` from the Affiliate linking docs: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

You can narrow searches (!) down to iPad only apps, which might be a solution you can look into. With enough search terms you might be able to narrow the search down to exactly the apps you wanna show, but there's the possibility for "other" apps getting into the search. Example: 
`http://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=microsoft+corporation+office&entity=iPadSoftware`

Comment: Thank you, that's not exactly what I need, but it was helpful.